# Stand up select services with docker-compose

Tags: deployment, docker, microservices, devops, software-distribution

I wanted to create a install script which would stand up certain services based on user input. I am using docker for the managing these services. With docker-compose I am able to define multiple services, but by default all the services defined in docker-compose.yml start. Is there any workaround for this ? Also, is this a terrible strategy [but all my services use docker, so is there an alternate way] ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to let us know a bit more detail about your use case?

Answer (score 16):

Do you mean:

`docker-compose up SERVICE` ?

That should start a single service and any linked containers.
You can also do:

`docker-compose run SERVICE [COMMAND] [ARGS...]`

which might be better for you depending on your needs, has some differences from `up` in how it's executed. See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Comment: Sounds like OP wants some but not all though (or some user-defined inputs), either way it sounds like there's going to be some orchestration outside of compose.

Comment: Probably, just wanted to make sure he was aware of the options. Some version using `run` still may be possible, depending on the use case and complexity of the services.

Comment: upv for more use case info please :D

Answer (score 12):

Starting with [`docker-compose` 1.28.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.28.0) the new [service profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) are just made for that! With `profiles` you can mark services to be only started in specific profiles:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    # ...

  database:
    # ...

  app-init:
    profiles: ["init"]
    # ...

  database-init:
    profiles: ["init"]
    # ...
```

```sh
docker-compose up # start only your core services
docker-compose --profile init up # start app and init services
docker-compose run database-init # run init service interactively
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip some services by scaling down.

`docker-compose up --scale unwanted-service1=0 --scale unwanted-service2=0`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out of the box in compose to help you with this. You're probably looking at scripting a thin layer / cli on top of this if you definitely want to go down this route.